# What is the perisomatic region of a neuron?

Tags: cell-biology, neuroscience, neurophysiology

In the scholarpedia page on [interneurons](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Interneurons) I encountered the following passage:

> The **perisomatic domain** is responsible for the summation of postsynaptic potentials arriving from all dendritic branches [...]. Thus, **the perisomatic region** - and particularly the axon initial segment [...] plays a crucial role in the generation of output.

The page, however, does not define what the perisomatic region really is. **What comprises the perisomatic region of an interneuron?**

Comment: Sure mate. If these edits are not to your liking feel free to roll it back. It's just that in the linked Scholarpedia page the term is not explained anywhere. Quoting the relevant section shows that to other users nicely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [cortical GABAergic cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interneuron) with local axonal projections, the perisomatic region is defined as that part of the plasma membrane including the [proximal dendrites](http://neurolex.org/wiki/Category:Proximal_Dendrite), the [cell body](http://www.cerebromente.org.br/n07/fundamentos/neuron/parts_i.htm) and the [axon initial segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axon_hillock) [(Zabó *et al*., 2010)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2916217/).

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Zabó *et al*., *Eur J Neurosci* (2010); **31**(12): 2234–46](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2916217/)</sub>

Comment: Now that I read your answer, maybe I should have deduced it from the name.. However I didn't so... Thank you!

Comment: @user135172 - No worries and happy to help - I had to look it up too. Nice question and well researched +1

Answer (score 1):

'Peri' = 'in the region of'

'soma' = 'cell body'

so the perisomatic region is the area in the region of the cell body - I thought the breakdown might be useful in future as 'peri' is used a lot.